# Prove statement related to dot product

Tags: calculus

$a, b$ and $x$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and satisfy 
$$a\cdot x=b\cdot x$$

Prove 
$$ a=b $$

By using the definition of dot product, I come up with something like
$$x_3(x_1-x_2)+y_3(y_1-y_2)+z_3(z_1-z_2)=0$$

At first, I want to make the conclusion from the equation because it holds only when $x_1=x_2$, $y_1=y_2$ and $z_1=z_2$, that is $a=b$. But what if $x$ is a zero vector? How can I prove this statement?

Comment: It's not true, so you're gonna have a hard time proving it.

Comment: If $(a-b)\cdot x=0$ then $a-b$ is just perpendicular to $x$ - certainly, we can't conclude $a-b=0$.

Comment: Maybe you mean $a\cdot x = b\cdot x$ for all $x$, then $a=b$?

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming from the comments this is what you meant to prove. Let $a, b \in \mathbb R^3$ be vectors satisfying for **all** $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $a \cdot x = b \cdot x$. Then $a = b$.

**Proof**: Since for all $x \in \mathbb R^3, a \cdot x = b \cdot x$, we have that $(a-b) \cdot x = 0$. Write $(a-b) = [c_1, c_2, c_3]$. Then $(a-b) \cdot [1,0,0] = c_1 = 0, (a-b) \cdot [0,1,0] = c_2 = 0, (a-b) \cdot [0,0,1] = c_3 = 0$. And so $a-b = [0,0,0]$, implying $a = b$.